# SQL query works in SSMS but not in VB.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, view, odbc

I have this query which returns a datatable from a view, it works perfect inside SSMS, but when I try to use it within VB.net it returns

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime, data type resulted in an out-of-range value

[image: View in SSMS:]

SQL in SSMS (Executes without problem):

```sql
SELECT [Consecutivo], [Detalle], [MetodoPago], [Fecha], [Concepto], [Monto], [Recuperacion], [Usuario], [UsuarioNombre] FROM [BD_RentaEquipos].[dbo].[Cierres] WHERE datediff(day, [Fecha],'2020/05/12')=0
```

SQL in VB.NET (Doesn't execute):

```vb
Public Function C_Cargar(Optional Fecha As Date? = Nothing) As DataTable
    Dim LeTable As New dsTablas.CierresDataTable
    AbrirConexion()
    'Dim SQL = "SELECT [Consecutivo], [Detalle], [MetodoPago], [Fecha], [Concepto], [Monto], [Recuperacion], [Usuario], [UsuarioNombre] FROM [BD_RentaEquipos].[dbo].[Cierres]" & IIf(Fecha IsNot Nothing, " WHERE datediff(day, [Fecha], '" & New String(Fecha.Value.Year & "/" & Fecha.Value.Month & "/" & Fecha.Value.Day) & "') = 0", "")
    Dim SQL = "SELECT [Consecutivo], [Detalle], [MetodoPago], [Fecha], [Concepto], [Monto], [Recuperacion], [Usuario], [UsuarioNombre] FROM [BD_RentaEquipos].[dbo].[Cierres]" & IIf(Fecha IsNot Nothing, " WHERE datediff(day, [Fecha], ? ) = 0", "")
    cmd = New OdbcCommand(SQL)
    Dim data As OdbcDataReader
    cmd.Connection = CN
    If Fecha IsNot Nothing Then
        With Fecha.Value
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Fecha)
            'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", New String(.Day & "/" & .Month & "/" & .Year))
        End With
    End If
    Try
        data = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While data.Read
            LeTable.Rows.Add()
            With LeTable.Rows(LeTable.Rows.Count - 1)
                .Item("Consecutivo") = data("Consecutivo")
                .Item("Detalle") = data("Detalle").ToString
                .Item("MetodoPago") = data("MetodoPago").ToString
                .Item("Fecha") = data("Fecha")
                .Item("Concepto") = data("Concepto").ToString
                .Item("Monto") = data("Monto")
                .Item("Recuperacion") = data("Recuperacion")
                .Item("Usuario") = data("Usuario")
                .Item("UsuarioNombre") = data("UsuarioNombre")
            End With
        End While
    Catch sqlerror As SqlException
        MsgBox(sqlerror.Message & Chr(13) & sqlerror.Procedure, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Excecion de Base de datos #" & sqlerror.Number)
        Err.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Excecion de Base de datos #" & "0x" & Hex(ex.HResult))
        Err.Clear()
    Finally
        CerrarConexion()
    End Try
    Return LeTable
End Function
```

I tried different ways without results

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Dan makes a specific point with Datetime values though your issue is related to both the wrong implied datatype and the use of a string.

Comment: Change '?' by @Fecha

Comment: @Smor ok, im trying that way but dunno why each time I get and error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter'.`

Comment: Been trying with
`Dim dparameter As OdbcParameter = New OdbcParameter("@Fecha", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = Fecha
        cmd.Parameters.Add(dparameter)`

And with
`cmd.Parameters.Add(New OdbcParameter("@Fecha", OdbcType.DateTime)) '.Value = Fecha`

Comment: May I ask why you are using ODBC when Sql Server has its own provider?

Comment: Using ODBC means the sql you write is less specific to the given server. You can swap out the SQL server to MySQL, or even Access, and you ONLY have to change the ODBC driver (connection string). Your provider code does not have to be changed. So, it easer to change your data source you are consuming from. sqlProvider is only  for sql server and thus you have to change both provider code and connection strings if you want to re-use the code for a different (non) sql server data source. With ODBC, you only have to change the connection string - not your provider code for different source.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, never use IIF if you can help it, secondly dates as string should be in ISO format (yyyy-MM-did)

```
Dim SQL = $"SELECT [Consecutivo], [Detalle], [MetodoPago], 
                   [Fecha], [Concepto], [Monto], [Recuperacion], 
                   [Usuario], [UsuarioNombre] 
            FROM [BD_RentaEquipos].[dbo].[Cierres]
            " 


cmd = New OdbcCommand()
Dim data As OdbcDataReader
cmd.Connection = CN
If Fecha IsNot Nothing Then
    SQL +=  " WHERE cast([Fecha] as date) = '?' ")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
End If
cmd.CommandText = SQL
```

Also, this is one of the situations where you don’t actually need a parameter, you are dealing with a date and can format it and include it as part of the sql text directly, although I didn’t.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned SSMS I thought you were probably using SQL Server. To use the Sql provider

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

It is good to keep your database objects local to the method where they are used so you can be sure they are closed and disposed. (they may be using unmanaged resources which are released in their `.Dispose` method) The `Using...End Using` blocks assure this even if there is an error. Both the connection and command are in a single Using block in this sample code. Note the comma at the end of the first line of the `Using`.

You can pass your connection string directly to the constructor of the connection.

When you use parameters with the `.Add` method you designate the `SqlDbType` so the server knows what to expect. You are passing in a .net `Date` type so there is not need to format any strings. ADO will figure it out for you.

If you need to use ODBC for some reason the just replace Sql types with Odbc.

The returned `DataTable` can be used directly as a `.DataSource` for a `DataGridView` in WinForms.

```
    Public Function C_Cargar(Optional Fecha As Date? = Nothing) As DataTable
    Dim LeTable As New DataTable
    Dim SQL = "SELECT [Consecutivo], [Detalle], [MetodoPago], [Fecha], [Concepto], [Monto], [Recuperacion], [Usuario], [UsuarioNombre] FROM [BD_RentaEquipos].[dbo].[Cierres]"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand()
        If Fecha IsNot Nothing Then
            SQL &= " WHERE datediff(day, [Fecha], @Fecha)=0;"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Fecha
        End If
        cmd.CommandText = SQL
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cn.Open()
        LeTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return LeTable
End Function
```